# How to calculate the difference between 2 dates properly php

Tags: php, date, datetime, date-difference

I'm trying to calculate the difference between 2 dates for a php project.

For example:
What is the difference between 2nd of April to 1st of June?

**First method of calculating the difference**
From 2nd of April to 2nd of may = 1 month. From 2nd of May to 1 of June = 30 days. => 2nd of April to 1th of June = 1 month and 30 days

**Second method of calculating the difference**
We count may as 1 month. Then add the days from 2nd to the 30th of April (28 days) and the days from June (1 day) => 1 month and 29 days.

I consider the first method as the correct one, simply because I think most of the people calculate this way.

So at first I tried to use the DateTime::diff() function

```
function dateDiff($date1, $date2 = false) {
if (!$date2)
    $date2 = date('Y-m-d');

$datetime1 = new DateTime($date1 , new DateTimeZone('EUROPE/Sofia'));
$datetime2 = new DateTime($date2 , new DateTimeZone('EUROPE/Sofia'));

$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

$y = $interval->format('%y');
$m = $interval->format('%m');
$d = $interval->format('%d');

return $y . " " . $m . " " . $d;

}
```

BUT I noticed it wasn't calculating the difference correctly.
The difference between '2015-02-03' and '2015-04-02' should be **1 month and 30 days**, (02-03 to 03-03 = 1 month. Then we count the rest of the days to 04-02, which are 30),  **BUT** the diff calculated it as **1 month and 27 days** (I guess it is calculating the difference by the second method that I stated above). Therefore it is either calculating wrong or the second method is the correct way of calculating.

BUT
Lets examine this example:
2015-05-01 and 2015-03-31 (we are going backward this time). The diff returns **1 month** difference, where I think it should be **1 month and 1 day**.

Furthermore the difference between 2015-05-01 and 2015-02-28 should be **2 months and 1 day**, but the diff function returns **2 months and 3 days**.

So, which is the correct way of calculating difference between 2 dates? Is the DateTime::diff() calculating properly? And is there a way to calculate difference between two dates by the first method.

Comment: https://github.com/fightbulc/moment.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should calculate the difference correctly.

```
function monthDiff($m1, $m2) {
    if($m1 > $m2) {
        return 12 - $m1 + $m2;
    }
    return $m2 - $m1;
}

function yearDiff($y1, $y2) {
    return $y2 - $y1;
}


function checkLeapYear($year){
    $year = (int)$year;
    return ( ( ($year % 4 == 0 && ($year % 100) != 0 ) || ( ($year % 100) == 0 && ($year % 400) == 0 ) ) ? 1 : 0);
}


function dateDiff($date1, $date2 = false) {
    if (!$date2)
        $date2 = date('Y-m-d');

    $datetime1 = new DateTime($date1 , new DateTimeZone('EUROPE/Sofia'));
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($date2 , new DateTimeZone('EUROPE/Sofia'));

    if($datetime1 > $datetime2){ //always go from smaller to bigger date
        $temp = $datetime1;
        $datetime1 = $datetime2;
        $datetime2 = $temp; 
    }

    $d1 = (int)$datetime1->format('d');
    $d2 = (int)$datetime2->format('d');

    $m1 = (int)$datetime1->format('m');
    $m2 = (int)$datetime2->format('m');

    $y1 = (int)$datetime1->format('Y');
    $y2 = (int)$datetime2->format('Y');


    $leapYear = checkLeapYear($y1); 
    $daysInMonth1 = [1 => 31, 28 + $leapYear, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]; // the number of days in the months

    $leapYear = checkLeapYear($y2);
    $daysInMonth2 = [1 => 31, 28 + $leapYear, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];


    $monthCorrection = 0;


    if ($d1 < $d2) {
        $d = $d2 - $d1; 
    }

    if ($d1 > $d2){
        if ($daysInMonth2[$m2] >= $d1){ 
            $d = $daysInMonth1[$m1] - $d1 + $d2;;
        }
        else {
            $d = $daysInMonth1[$m1] - $d1 + $d2;
        }
        $monthCorrection = -1;
    }

    if ($d1 == $d2 ){
        $d = 0;
    }

    $m = monthDiff($m1, $m2) + $monthCorrection;

    $y = yearDiff($y1, $y2);
    if ($m1 > $m2){
        $y--;
    }

    return $y . " years " . $m . " months " . $d . " days";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Php has bug with [`DateInterval`](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52480). For now you can try use external implementations like [Moment](https://github.com/fightbulc/moment.php) library, or follow bug status and wait when it will fixed.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a little example, hope it helps

```
$date1 = strtotime("2015-01-01"); //yyyy-mm-dd
$date2 = strtotime("2015-01-08");
$datediff = $date2 - $date1;
echo floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
```